# Parar Loop For quando for digitado um determinado número

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, loop, for

Estou tentando parar um loop for quando for digitado o número 42. Até a gora meu código esta assim:

```js
var numero = prompt('Digite o numero')
var arrNumero  = []
arrNumero.push(numero)
console.log(arrNumero)

for (let i = 0; i < arrNumero.length; i++) {
 if (arrNumero[i] === '42') {
    break;
 } else {
        console.log(arrNumero[i])
 }
}
```

Ao digitar o número 42 o for não para com a instrução break. Gostaria de saber de vocês como faço para não imprimir o número 42 no console.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, não seria só remover o console.log. Abaixo da linha : `arrNumero.push(numero)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executei seu código e funciona normalmente, assim fica até mais fácil de ver:

```
var numero = prompt('Digite o numero')
var arrNumero  = [1,2,3,numero,5,6,7]
console.log(arrNumero)

for (let i = 0; i < arrNumero.length; i++) {
 if (arrNumero[i] === '42') {
    break;
 } else {
        console.log(arrNumero[i])
 }
}
```